# How to share files between pipelines in different repositories?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have two pipelines: one creates binary files, the other one uses this binary file.
For this, I need to share the files created by the first pipeline to the other one.
I tried using the Publish Artifact task, but I get an error message when trying to download the artifacts in the second pipeline.

This is the pipeline configuration for the first pipeline:

```
steps:
#this script creates the binaries
- script: do something
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/path/to/folder
  artifact: artifact1
```

This is the pipeline configuration for the second pipeline:

```
steps:
- download: current
  artifact: artifact1
```

This second pipeline fails with the following error: `##[error]Artifact artifact1 was not found for build 123.`

I think the reason for this error might be that published artifacts are only available in jobs of the same pipeline run. Is this correct?
If so then how can I share these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `specific` instead of `current` if you are downloading from a artifact published by another pipeline:

```
steps:
- download: specific
  artifact: artifact1
```

Check this out:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    source: 'specific'
    project: 'FabrikamFiber'
    pipeline: 12
    runVersion: 'latest'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops#download-artifacts-from-a-specific-projectpipeline